# submit form inside div, not working with IE8 when submitting with ENTER

Tags: javascript, css, forms, internet-explorer

i have a form ( login, registration, whatever ) which is inside a div.

The div has `visibility: hidden` and gets `visibility:visible` through javascript.

In **IE8**, when a user completes the form ( username, password ) and then uses the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press to submit it, it won't work ( it will work if he presses the login button ).

html:

```
<body onload="show_login();">
<div id="login" class="login_div">
<form id="form_login" method="post" action="index.php">
<input name="Email" id="Email" type="text" maxlength="100" size="30" />
<input name="Password" id="Password" type="password" maxlength="100" size="30" />
<input name="FromSubmit" id="FromSubmit" type="hidden" value="FromSubmit"/>
<button id="bLogin" type="submit"><span id="sLogin">Log In</span></button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.login_div {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

js:

```
function show_login() {
    document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Maybe someone has come across this problem before ?

Any way to solve it without affecting the JS logic ?

**EDIT**

If I remove the doctype it does work, but I don't want to remove it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Should it not be `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: The `type="submit"` is valid for the button-element, too.

Comment: in my local it works\

Comment: It works on my side. Make sure the cursor is focused on a field inside the form.

Comment: Try use css attribute display:none and display:block as visibility in your div to see if it works. Maybe is some another freak IE bug.

Comment: @Jude try with <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> it won't work. updated my original post

Comment: @JohnPrado i tried with display: none but it's  the same... the bug seems to be caused by the doctype

Comment: SPAN inside a button is blocking in IE8. You can add CSS to button by adding class attribute or by it's ID.

Comment: You could use the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This is backward compatible! http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype